# Will MXML ever "compile" to html5?

Tags: apache-flex, html

My question may be silly but I think it´s not.

I´m using flex with Ruby on Rails backend to develop rich internet apps. Recently flash has been attacked, an example is Steve Job´s [thoughts on Flash](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/).

I think flex is a wonderfull tool, but to be honest I really would rather to have a tool as productive as flex but compliant with open standards.

For me, in a perfect world I would code in MXML just like I do now and Flex Builder would build a pure html5 front-end.

My question is, is it likely to happen? It is allowed to dream anything, right... :-)

Comment: Not likely would be an understatement. :)

Comment: This question requires a crystal ball to answer.  Whether or not it's *possible* would be answerable.  Whether it will be implemented and allowed by Apple are other matters that we can't answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it likely to happen? No.

Is it allowed to dream anything, yes.

MXML is an XML vocabulary designed to generate ActionScript, which is the underlying language of Flash. Since ActionScript is based on ECMAScript, the same standard as JavaScript, it's possible that MXML could be adapted to output JavaScript. But the reason it doesn't is because JavaScript doesn't yet have the same capabilities as ActionScript.

Comment: Not so fast - if HTML5 is supposedly going to "kill" Flash, it had *darn* well better have the same capabilities. (Or is HTML5 more hype than substance?) Also, one of the top Flex features now is an HTML5 compiler. If Google can do it with Java (which is probably more different than Flash is from JavaScript, being multi-threaded for one), Adobe should be able to do it with ActionScript. They have some compiler expertise (Flash has JIT), so let's change "not likely to happen" to a "possibly"!

Comment: http://csharksgames.blogspot.com/2009/07/jangaroo-html-5-killer-as3-to-js.html

Comment: Correction to the above - one of the top Flex **feature requests** (not completed features) on Adobe Labs is an HTML5 compiler.

Comment: http://ideas.adobe.com/ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?c=975F47A1-B925-4456-89DB-3BEFB1DA7780&idea_id=3AAF1D0A-A4E2-41AB-B55C-A13942CD4E19

Comment: There is a small but active effort to do just this in the official Apache Flex repository, with a new version of the SDK called FlexJS. MXML is just a shorthand way of expressing things in actionscript. The ASC compiler used to just convert it to actionscript, Falcon (the final/latest compiler) just converts it to straight up ABC. Essentially if you have the core (like display list etc) done in javascript, you could compile MXML and Actionscript to pure functional javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that MXML or Flex would ever have an output to HTML.  To make that work they would need an HTML version of The Flex Framework, which would most likely be written in JavaScript.  It seems very unlikely to me.

I believe one of the sneak peaks at the last Adobe Max conference, they did show a Flash Professional animation exported to HTML5.

*[Start Speculation]*
I assumed the HTML version was making use of the Canvas elements in HTML5, while resources were most likely PNG.
*[End Speculation]*

But I honestly have no idea how it actually worked.
You can probably find videos on-line of the sneaks.  Good luck!

Comment: See my other comment. By the way, I just remembered, Adobe announced just such a project, and here's this: http://csharksgames.blogspot.com/2009/07/jangaroo-html-5-killer-as3-to-js.html  I don't think it's an "HTML5 killer" but it's certainly not a bad thing for Adobe and Flex.

Comment: @Crusader You are confused on a few things.  First, there is no indication that Jangaroo is an Adobe project.  Can you provide a source for your claim that it is?  Second, Jangaroo is an ActionScript 3 compiler. There is no support for MXML listed on the Jangaroo site.  Can you provide a source for your claim that Jangaroo supports Flex Applications?  Supporting ActionScript 3 and supporting Flex are the same thing. MXML is not the same as AS3.   Third, Jangaroo is not unique.  There are similar Flash to JS projects out there; but most seem extremely limited.

Comment: The Adobe Flash to HTML Project is code named Wallaby and available for download from Adobe Labs: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/wallaby/ .  This is the same project I mentioned in my answer that was demoed at Adobe Max last year.

Comment: No no, I'm not saying it is Adobe's.  There IS a separate article where Adobe announced a project of their own, but it's not Jangaroo.  I pointed that out to show that similar things have been done before, so certainly Adobe can pull it off.  However I see you found the actual Adobe project (which no doubt was the one I read the announcement about awhile back). I don't know why you'd doubt Flex will eventually be supported. This is one of the top requested Flex features now. If Flash really does ever start being challenged, such a feature would be fantastic for the Flex SDK and toolset.

Comment: And being that the Flash/Flex tools are sold by Adobe, they have some financial motivation to keep them relevant. Current Flash tools are better than their HTML-JS hack writing counterparts.

Comment: @Crusader Wallaby is the tool I mentioned in my original post. I don't think at the time it was available on Adobe labs yet.  It is now.  And it does not support Flex or MXML.  Supporting animations and supporting advanced ActionScript code in HTML are two radically different endeavors.

Comment: @Crusader do you have a source for the claim that it is a major Flex feature?  Or are you just looking to institute a flame war?

Comment: Major Flex feature **request** on Labs (ahh! There was a typo, missing the word **request** on my first comment on the other answer!). "Compile to html5" is the 6th top "idea" on Adobe Labs for the Flex SDK. With the mistype I see where you were coming from now, but I still don't understand why you are being so hostile and provoking. Link, if it works: http://ideas.adobe.com/ct/ct_list.bix?c=975F47A1-B925-4456-89DB-3BEFB1DA7780&tag=&tab=1&status=&cat_id=&page=2&txtKeywords=&status_tab=

Comment: @Crusader You were the one who said that the Flex framework was inferior and substandard.  I forget your exact words as that comment is now gone.  I'm unsure what I'm doing to be hostile.

Comment: Huh? Miscommunicating--I said the JS/browser environment was inferior and substandard to the **Flash** environment. Not sure what happened to that, I know I didn't delete anything on purpose (surely we are entitled to our opinions without being censored shadow moderators?). I mean, I think we're on the same side of the fence here. I hated developing within browser-based chaos and will not leave the stability of the Flash platform until (if?) the clowns working on these buggy DOM/HTML 'platforms' get their act together on standardization and backwards compatibility, like Flash has had forever.

Comment: My primary skillset is Flex/Java, so either my other comment was unclear or you're recalling it wrong. :) I mean I do feel Flex can be improved but I'd never call it inferior and substandard--(to what?)

Answer (score -1):

Simple. MXML was introduced to replace HTML. I doubt they would come where you can generate a HTML 5 generated code. Not possible, and i doubt even adobe would come up too.